# Need to implement multiple QueryStringBinder.scala class in my play project

Tags: scala, playframework, query-string

The case class in existing QueryStringBinder.scala already supports 22 parameters and I am unable to add new parameters required to be supported.
As a workaround , I created another class NewQueryStringBinder.scala  in order to support the additional parameters.
So now both classes are using the `bind` and `unbind` methods of QueryStringBindable:

```
implicit def binder(implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[Option[String]]): QueryStringBindable[NewQueryParams] =
new QueryStringBindable[NewQueryParams] {
  override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, NewQueryParams]] = {........


object QueryParamsBinder {
implicit def binder(implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[Option[String]]): QueryStringBindable[QueryParams] =
new QueryStringBindable[QueryParams] {
  override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, QueryParams]] = {.......
```

As a result, there are plenty of compilation errors looking like:

```
  No QueryString binder found for type binders.QueryParams. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.
```

I need to implement both the `QueryStringBinder` and `NewQueryStringBinder` classes successfully.

I am using Play version `2.2.4`

Kindly advise a solution.

Comment: If both traits `QueryStringBindable` and `NewQueryStringBinder` have the same signature/semantics and would be implemented by same instances, then it hard to see a value for sych new trait

Comment: `NewQueryStringBinder` is the class implementing `QueryStringBindable` trait.`QueryStringBindable` is also implemented by `QueryStringBinder` class